# Invalid Object Name in MVC DB First app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, db-first

I'm running into a frequent MVC DB first issue where everytime I update my domain model classes from the DB, something always seems to be breaking. In this case, after adding another table and model into my project, running  **Update model From Database** and **Generate Model From DB** in the .EDMX file, a perfectly good table  with a working query is causing the Invalid Object Name error when the app runs in the browser.

I've cleaned and rebuilt my project multiple times. Everything compiles and the error only occurs when the app tries to run in the browser.

Is DB First prone to being buggy or am I not doing something properly when using DB first approach?

Error Screens
[image: First Error]

[image: Stack trace]

Comment: Pls post your error screen.

Comment: Added error screens

Comment: Check ur EF does this table exists in .edmx. Also open .edmx as xml for the same

Comment: Yes it exists in both